# Catalina login screen hangs after power related restart

Tags: catalina, performance, reboot

When the battery runs out on my MBP, after plugging in and pressing the power button, I am greeted with the login screen. I type my password, then it hangs and the only thing I can do is hard switch off, then reboot, and everything works perfectly again. I never saw this problem on 10.14.

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014), Catalina 10.15.3 (19D76).

Any suggestions where to look?

Comment: Try NVRAM Reset to fix it https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063